# Upgrading from sqlalchemy 1.3 to 1.4 breaks hybrid property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The am using a hybrid property to code JSONB properties to sqlalchemy fields, however after upgrading to 1.4 this functionality no longer works and the column key name does not come through in dictionary requests. What needs to be altered so that the response brings through the correct column name rather than anon_1?

```
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, select
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeclarativeMeta
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def create_postgres():
    engine = create_engine(os.environ["TEST_DATABASE"], poolclass=StaticPool)
    engine.execute("SET search_path TO pg_temp")

    @listens_for(engine, "engine_connect")
    def set_search_path(connection, branch):
        connection.execute("SET search_path TO pg_temp")

    return engine

@pytest.fixture
def session(request):
    engine = create_postgres()

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    return Session(engine)


def update_json_property_names(attrs):
    for key, value in attrs.items():
        if isinstance(value, hybrid_property) and hasattr(value.fget, "__json_property"):
            setattr(value.fget, "prop_key", key)

def json_property(json_column, name, type_=None):
    def instance_get(self):
        return getattr(self, json_column.key)[name]

    def instance_set(self, value):
        json_obj = getattr(self, json_column.key)
        if json_obj is None:
            setattr(self, json_column.key, {})
        getattr(self, json_column.key)[name] = value

    def cls_get(cls):
        if type_:
            return json_column.cast(JSONB)[name].astext.cast(type_)
        else:
            return json_column.cast(JSONB)[name]

    prop = hybrid_property(
        fget=instance_get,
        expr=cls_get,
        fset=instance_set
    )

    prop.__json_property = (json_column.key, name)

    return prop


class ModelMetaType(DeclarativeMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        update_json_property_names(attrs)
        return DeclarativeMeta.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)



Base = declarative_base(metaclass=ModelMetaType)


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "author"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)

    born = json_property(data, "yearBorn", Integer())
    died = json_property(data, "yearDied")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Author(id={!r}, name={!r}, data={!r})".format(
            self.id, self.name, self.data
        )

def test_expression_has_name_of_json_property(session):
    session.add(Author(data={"yearBorn": 1881}))
    session.commit()
    q = select(Author.born)
    result = session.execute(q).one()
    assert result._asdict() == {"born": 1881}
```

I receive {'anon_1': 1881} rather than {"born": 1881}

Comment: How does `update_json_property_names` get called?

Comment: sorry appears to be a copy and paste error, it is call in class ModelMetaType. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `update_json_property_names` function, `value.fget` is checked for `__json_property`, but `_json_property` is an attribute of `value`, so the function can be changed to:

```py
def update_json_property_names(attrs):
    for key, value in attrs.items():
        if isinstance(value, hybrid_property) and hasattr(value, "__json_property"):
            setattr(value.fget, "prop_key", key)
```

once this change has been made, we can set a label on the expression:

```py
def json_property(json_column, name, type_=None):
    ...

    def cls_get(cls):
        if type_:
            return json_column.cast(JSONB)[name].astext.cast(type_).label(instance_get.prop_key)
        else:
            return json_column.cast(JSONB)[name].label(instance_get.prop_key)
```

and the test passes.